# Compare multiple variables and perform an Include function

Tags: php, html

I have a website with multiple categories and I have created one social links php page for each category. I have created a php function to obtain php file based on last-word of URL. I want the function to occur If only last-word matches the names of Categories. ex:cat1, cat2, cat3 etc...

I would like to know whether there is a chance to compare a variable with multiple strings and output as boolean If the variable value matches any of the string value.

Also please send the code to occur function, When the boolean value is true only.

Your help and patience are much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

`URl: domain.com/cat1`
Last_word is cat1

last_words we need to have are cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4..
Include php file cat1-sociallinks.php

If last_word is cat2 then, Include php file cat1-sociallinks.php

If last_word is something other than the cat#, then dont include php sociallinks.php file.

Comment: _...Also please send the code to..._ What code?

Comment: I want PHP code to occur a function, based on boolean value. Sorry, If my English is not good.

Comment: "would like to know whether there is a chance to compare a variable with multiple strings and output as boolean If the variable value matches any of the string value". Yes, of course. In the simplest case you can use a loop, and check a different string on each iteration of the loop. There's probably a more sophisticated way too, but that's the basic idea to get you started. Try it out. If you get stuck, post your code and explain your problem. On this site we generally _help_ you with your code, not just provide it all for you ready-made.